# Unable to turn a folder into root path Static Content for Kestrel C# dotnet standard. Nothing is working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-standard, kestrel-http-server

I need to turn an arbitrary folder in my C drive into a 'wwwroot' folder, meaning anything put in there will be served via http.
I think this is called 'Static Files' (Correct me if i'm wrong)
I'm running a stand alone Dot Net 4.72 Console APP.

**I've tried almost every solution out there in Stack Overflow but nothing works**. I keep getting the following error on chrome when i browse 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html'

> This page isn’t working
> 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

My setup can't get any simpler.  I'm running this on DotNet 4.72 =>

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(@"C:\my\src\bytebix\www")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(l => Console.WriteLine(l))
            .Build();
            host.RunAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop...");               
Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup() { }

            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
                {
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\my\src\bytebix\www")
                });
            }
        }
```

When run, i see the following

[image]

In chrome, i see the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Try `localhost`, not `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I tried it, it still didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps there's also a problem calling `UseStaticFiles` twice.

Comment: Done that too.. Deleted one of them and vice versa.. still didn't work.. same problem